# How to export some data by python requests library with REST Api?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, rest

I have a problem with some exercise from Python based on the requests library and a REST API. I need to find some information from https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts . I need to code which will:

- connect to this address (requests library)
- list a number of all interesting facts about cats in this website.
- list 10 facts with the most votes
- list names and surnames of users which posted some "facts about cats"

I'm just a beginner with Python and truly this is too much for me right now. It's case from my studies.

I'm right here:

```
import json
import requests
def get_cat_data():
   url='https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts'
   response=requests.get(url)
   response_json=response.json()
   cat_data=response_json['text']
   output=[]
   for x in cat_data:
      output.append("{text}".format(cat_data))
```

Comment: Please, don't delete my post this time guys, I really need help

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I'm not sure, if it would help you, in case someone code them for you. (Check [ask]). Take some time, and try some tutorials, those would help you to come further in your study. Trust me, I've been through that.... (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw)

Comment: You mention that you want to list 10 facts with the most votes, but looking at the returned data, there's no votes field?

Comment: I see it now, there must be a mistake in task. How about the first task - a number of all interesting facts about cats in this website?